# Imagemagick -canny : what do arguments refer to?

Tags: imagemagick, imagick

When using the -canny option of the Imagemagick convert tool, what do these arguments refer to ?

`-canny radiusxsigma{+lower-percent}{+upper-percent}`

The documentation (https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#canny) gives examples of what increase or decrease of percents may result in, but I can't find the exact meaning of radiusXsigma and its relation to the two numbers following (i.e. 10% and 30% in the doc example).

Comment: As with a lot of Imagemagick and Imagick options the information is a bit sketchy.

snidgo a Imagemagick forum member has some more detailed examples on his site: http://im.snibgo.com/canny.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be worth jumping over to wikipedia's definition of [Canny edge detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) article.

The documentation assumes you are already aware of [Gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function).
Both `radius` and `sigma` are user-defined constants; perhaps, best described by the [`GaussianBlurImage` method](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/f6ff9eaa865134189fce2cf73b109da589178bde/MagickCore/effect.c#L1342) header documentation.  (quote below)

> `GaussianBlurImage()` blurs an image.  We convolve the image with a
>   Gaussian operator of the given `radius` and standard deviation (`sigma`).
>   For reasonable results, the `radius` should be larger than `sigma`.  Use a
>   `radius` of `0` and `GaussianBlurImage()` selects a suitable radius for you
>
> The format of the GaussianBlurImage method is:
>
> ```
> Image *GaussianBlurImage(const Image *image,onst double radius,
>                    const double sigma,ExceptionInfo *exception)
> ```
>
> A description of each parameter follows:
>
> - `image:` the image.
> - `radius:` the radius of the Gaussian, in pixels, not counting the center pixel.
> - `sigma:` the *standard deviation* of the Gaussian, in pixels.
> - `exception:` return any errors or warnings in this structure.

Better hands-on docs w/ examples [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/#blur_args).

Now for the last two options...

> `{+lower-percent}{+upper-percent}`

They are essentially lower & upper bounds of a threshold. Defining an "envelope", or "range", if you will. They'll essentially make up the [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector#Edge_tracking_by_hysteresis) to track.

Comment: In the ImageMagick documents, see http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#canny